# How does an MSP file contain a file that was rolled back to the original version?

Tags: windows-installer, msi-patch

If I have an MSP file, *AB.msp*, that was created from two MSI files, *A.msi* (older) and *B.msi* (newer), it's natural that one can apply *AB.msp* to an environment where *A.msi* is installed.

But, suppose there are several more MSI files between *A.msi* and *B.msi*, say, *C1.msi*, *C2.msi*, ... Here, I don't understand well how *AB.msp* can be applied evenly well to an environment where one of these *Cn.msi* files is installed. *AB.msp* was just created based on the difference between *A.msi* and *B.msi*. So, as I think, it only knows the difference between the two MSI files.

As an example, suppose a file *F1.exe* in *A.msi* was changed first in *C3.msi*, and it was rolled back in *B.msi*. Then *AB.msp* may think there is no difference in file *F1.exe* between *A.msi* and *B.msi*. So it can't be applied properly to an environment where *C3.msi* (has a different *F1.exe*) is installed.

But this is not the case in reality. Actually, *AB.msp* above (maybe) applies well to any environment where one of the *Cn.msi* files is installed. I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: Normally you should have the Cn MSIs added as target in your patch project too, i.e. A.msi, C1.msi, C2.msi,... should be the targets and B.msi should be the upgraded image. This way the MSP built will contain all the info required to apply on all of them correctly. The only way it can apply to your Cn MSIs right now is if in those MSIs you have not generated a new upgrade code when you increased the version, and of course kept the MSI name the same (one of the main rules: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/patches.html)

Comment: sorry, I meant to say "a new productcode when you increased the version..."